# Mandrill Inbound Webhook

Tags: php, mandrill, webhooks

I've been looking for hours for an answer and still no closer.  I hope someone can help.

I've set up a mailbox route to pass to a page which it to retrieve particular info from the post event but no matter what I try on my own page $_POST['mandrill_events'] never seems to exist but if then test with http://requestb.in/ it is receiving something.  I've tried the following code among others to no success:

```
$test = (json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events']));
$testinfo = $test->event;
```

and

```
$test = json_encode(json_decode($_POST['mandrill_events']));
```

and

```
$data = $_POST;
$restult_data_decode = json_decode($data['mandrill_events']);
$message_id = $restult_data_decode[0]->_id;
```

and

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$info = json_encode($value);
```

and various alt versions of these.  any idea what I'm missing as this is my first time setting up a webhook and not sure if it is just a $_POST or if I need to do something with my server or using any particular 3rd party code etc.

Thanks

I'm reciving the following in an access file:

```
[22/Jan/2016:08:57:53 +0000] "POST /system/email-webhook.php HTTP/1.1" 200 257 "-" "Mandrill-Webhook/1.0"
```

so it does appear to be doing something, just that $_POST is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it had to do with rights on the receiving page.  I changed that and it worked from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just don't receive the `POST` request from mandrill, first of all check your server's access_log to make sure that mandrill request appears there with valid http code. Second, check that URL you are using for webhook works properly. Try to send `POST` request with `mandrill_events` by yourself (i.e you can use [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) ) and check what happens.

Comment: I've tried testing the data sent by mandrill http://requestb.in/zd241vzd?inspect by testing if(isset($_POST['mandrill_events'])) but it's not finding it.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. Did you check that your server is receiving mandrill's request? I mean not data inside $_POST, just regular http request, do you see it in access_log?

Comment: I think I've found a file that contains this info.  I have found a line:  [22/Jan/2016:08:57:53 +0000] "POST /system/email-webhook.php HTTP/1.1" 200 257 "-" "Mandrill-Webhook/1.0"  which appears to say at least that it is receiving something but no idea what the content is

Comment: Great, now you can be sure that you are getting request from mandrill. Now try to print into your application log the content of $_POST and you will see which data you are receiving from mandrill.

Comment: seems to be empty, nothing being found in the $_POST

Comment: Strange... Are you testing it with "send test" button in mandrill panel? If so maybe something wrong with php framework you are using. Sorry, to hard to say without seeing it(

Comment: no problem, do you know of any guides on setting something like this up as I'm finding it hard to find any